# how to correct this java code which uses BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I am trying to solve the 3rd problem of project Euler that needs a **12** digits number and the problem is that the code I wrote isn't running :(
would you help me figure it out ? 
The error is so confusing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "51475143 "
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:546)
    at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:675)
    at Euler.main(Euler.java:9)
```

**Here's the whole code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigInteger N = new BigInteger("600851475143 ");
    BigInteger PrimeNumber;

    for(long i=2;i<250000;i++)
    {
        String code=" ";
        for(long j=2;j<i;j++)
        {

            if(i%j==0)
                code="exit";
        }
        if(code=="exit")
            break;

        PrimeNumber=BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        BigInteger R=N.remainder(PrimeNumber);
        if(R.equals(0))
        {
            System.out.println(N.divide(R));
            System.out.println("That's The answer");
        }

    }



}
```

}

Comment: `"600851475143 "` contains a space

Comment: Not relevant to this specific issue, but you should learn about [how to compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: @azurefrog Or even better, to not represent state by strings. Here a boolean would be just as good, and in the general case an Enum would be better than a string (typos would be caught by the compiler for example)

Comment: `long` supports all 18 digit numbers and is easier to work with.

Comment: check BigInteger  comparison  in in your code ` if(R==S)` seems buggy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove space in :

```
BigInteger N = new BigInteger("600851475143 ");
```

to be :

```
BigInteger N = new BigInteger("600851475143");
```

Comment: Thanks . Sorry I am so wacky :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in the string.

```
BigInteger N = new BigInteger("600851475143 ");
```

Would now be...

```
BigInteger N = new BigInteger("600851475143");
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was answered above, there was a space symbol in your string.
To avoid such mistypes it's worth to use the `String.trim()` method which removes whitespaces in the beginning and at the end of the string.

Smth like:

```
String num = "600851475143 ";
BigInteger N = new BigInteger(num.trim());
```